# Is reconfiguration required when switching sql server machine to use a FQDN?

Tags: sql-server

I'm going to be changing the Primary DNS Suffix (not the NETBIOS name) of a Windows 2008R2 Server that does not belong to a windows domain (eg. a WORKGROUP computer) in order to give it a FQDN.

Is it necessary to reconfigure SQL Server in any way after doing so? I'm thinking specifically of the steps that are required when changing the NETBIOS name of the computer located here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, changing the dns suffix of the server should not necessitate any change at the SQL Server.

The age-old mantra of test, test, test, certainly applies if you are making a change to a production machine since there may be repercussions at the client end depending on how your clients address the machine.

Comment: Thank you for the info Max! As Ben Franklin said "By failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail" - which is why I wanted a solid answer on the server-side of things before going ahead with the change :)